# Data Studio - auto aggregation function

Tags: function, aggregation, looker-studio

I have problem in Google Data Studio as I want to create auto agreggation but it isn't possible to change for this, I got sum function. How to set auto metric?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aggregating the numerator and denominator by [SUM](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) should do the trick (copy-paste the below into the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) and click on `APPLY`):

```
SUM(T # Target - T # This Month) / SUM(T # Target)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/370c89fd-5016-441c-a93d-2efa188d5c22) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]